# Component meaning of ranger.forest

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, r-ranger

I'm working with [ranger](https://cran.r-project.org/package=ranger), a fast implementation of Random Forests. The problem is I have no idea how to interpret the `$forest` component of the result. The document simply says

> **`forest`**: Saved forest (If `write.forest` set to `TRUE`). Note that the variable IDs in the `split.varIDs` object do not necessarily
>   represent the column number in R.

Well, that isn't really helpful, so I tried inspecting its components myself, by their names are not self-explanatory.

```
> names(ranger(Species ~ ., data = iris)$forest)
 [1] "dependent.varID"            "num.trees"
 [3] "child.nodeIDs"              "split.varIDs"
 [5] "split.values"               "is.ordered"
 [7] "class.values"               "levels"
 [9] "independent.variable.names" "treetype"
```

Some components like `num.trees` are trivial to understand, but things like `child.nodeIDs` are really mind-blowing.

```
> ranger(Species ~ ., data = iris)$forest$child.nodeIDs[[1]]
[[1]]
 [1]  1  3  5  0  7  9 11  0  0  0 13 15  0  0  0  0  0

[[2]]
 [1]  2  4  6  0  8 10 12  0  0  0 14 16  0  0  0  0  0
```

Is it documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation for the `ranger::treeInfo` function: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ranger/versions/0.11.2/topics/treeInfo